# MS Access: show count per hour (even if there are no records in the time slot)

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I'm stuck, i think it should be simple but can't get it to work. I have a table 'tbTimeTable' with all the hours of the day.

tbTimeTable (only show the first 5 records, but it will end at 23:00 (24 records in total)

```
| ID | TimeStart | TimeStop |
|1   | 0:00      | 1:00     |
|2   | 1:00      | 2:00     |
|3   | 2:00      | 3:00     |
|4   | 3:00      | 4:00     |
|5   | 4:00      | 5:00     |
```

I have a totals query qryPartCountTotalsPerHour with the part count per hour.

```
| DateIn   | PartCount | PeriodIn | PerdiodOut |
|19-5-2021 | 221       |0:00      | 1:00       |
|19-5-2021 | 203       |1:00      | 2:00       |
|19-5-2021 | 201       |2:00      | 3:00       |
|19-5-2021 | 215       |6:00      | 7:00       |
|19-5-2021 | 174       |7:00      | 8:00       |
```

What I want, is to show the part count result for all the hours of the day and if there are no records in that hour then show 0 in the part count. So every Date in the DateIn field should show at least 24 records.

I tried this:

```
SELECT qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.DateIn, qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.PartCount, qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.PeriodOut, qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.PeriodOut
FROM tbTimeTable LEFT JOIN qryPartCountTotalsPerHour ON tbTimeTable.TimeStart = qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.PeriodIn
ORDER BY qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.DateIn;
```

I also tried to convert the PeriodIn and TimeStart just to an 'Hour' with the Hour() function but nothing works. I make mistake somewhere but can't find it.

Edit: tried to clarify that the DateIn contains more than one date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. This [topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/building-a-report-off-of-a-crosstab-query-with/cfffcb53-df74-4b62-aabc-c681fd818356) helped me to get the answer, specifically the answer from Ken Sheridan and his public database "Payments". This database should give you enough info to solve this or a similair problem. However I will give you a short brief of what I did.

So I created a query with the time table and all the log dates (no relationship between them) called qryCalendar. This resulted in the complete time table for each logging date.

Then I created a new query to show the final result:

```
SELECT qryCalendar.Date, qryCalendar.TimeStop, qryCalendar.TimeStart, Nz([qryPartCountTotalsPerHour].[PartCount],0) AS tPartCount
FROM qryCalendar LEFT JOIN qryPartCountTotalsPerHour ON (qryCalendar.TimeStop = qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.PeriodOut) AND (qryCalendar.Date = qryPartCountTotalsPerHour.DateIn)
ORDER BY qryCalendar.Date, qryCalendar.TimeStart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You need to aggregate by the *first* table:

```
SELECT t.PeriodIn, NZ(q.PartCount), q.PeriodOut, q.PeriodOut
FROM tbTimeTable as t LEFT JOIN 
     qryPartCountTotalsPerHour as q
     ON t.TimeStart = qryPqrtCountTotalsPerHour.PeriodIn
ORDER BY t.PeriodIn;
```

This works for your sample data.  It might get more complicated if more days are involved.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but yes multiple days are involved.

Comment: @NRIGO . . . You should probably ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and explanation on how to handle the multiple days.